# RegEx that will capture everything between two characters including multiline blocks

Tags: regex

I want to capture all text & blocks of text between <% and %>.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title Here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% include("/path/to/include") %>
<h1>Test Template</h1>
<p>Variable: <% print(second_var) %></p>
<%

variable = value;

foreach(params here)
{
    code here
}

%>
<p><a href="/" title="Home">Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried `\<\%(.*)\%\>` but that will capture everything including `<h1>Test Template</h1>` block as well.

Comment: Please, [don't parse HTML with regexen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Which regex engine are you using?

```
<%(.*?)%>
```

should work with the "dot matches newline" option enabled. If you don't know how to set that, try

```
<%([\s\S]*?)%>
```

or

```
(?s)<%(.*?)%>
```

No need to escape `<`, `%`, or `>` by the way.

Answer (score 9):

`\<\%(.*?)\%\>`. You need to use `.*?` to get non-greedy pattern matching.

**EDIT** To solve the multiline problem, you can't use the `.` wildcard, as it matches everything except newline. This option differs depending on your regular expressions engine. So, I can tell you what to do if you tell me your regex engine.

Comment: some regex engine take `\<` for _beginning of word_ and `\>` for _end of word_

Comment: @Stijn: in that case, you can just escape \< and \>

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Microsoft's Regex engine (provided by JScript in IE) and it has a 'multi-line' switch that effects the behaviour of `.`, but then still I've had problems I had to resolve using `[\u0000-\uFFFF]` which matches *everything* including EOL's or any control chars...

So have a go with `<%([\u0000-\uFFFF]*?)%>`

Comment: The multiline (`m`) modifier does not affect the behavior of `.`.  It's the single-line (DOTALL, `s`) modifier that does that, but JavaScript doesn't support it.  The most common idiom for matching anything-including-newlines in JavaScript is `[\s\S]`, as @Tim demonstrated in his answer.